# Nimbus client to submit topology with arguments

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to submit my storm topology jar using java program. Currently using nimbus clinet api to submit the topology. I am able to run the command from command line "storm jar topologytest-1.0.jar com.test.topology.Main 10.10.2.1:2181" to submit my topology and it works fine. But i am not sure, how to add my arguments(com.test.topology.Main and 10.10.2.1:2181) to the topology while submitting programmatically. There is a method submitTopologyWithOpts in backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus.Client but not sure how to set the options in it.

Answer (score 0):

com.test.topology.Main is not an argument. It is the class to which following arguments (10.10.2.1:2181) are passed. In topology, you can pass any parameter through the config map.

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, configuration, topology);
```

In configuration, you can set the parameters you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i agree that we add configuration information of storm using map. For example  storm_conf.put("nimbus.host", "localhost") to set the nimnbus host. But what is the key we need use to set in the config map for aruguments ? Please suggest for multiple aruguments as well.

Comment: You can define a key yourself and use that. storm_conf.put("customkeystring", "customargument")